# How to fire C# DataGridView SelectionChanged event programmatically?

Tags: c#, user-interface, event-handling

I have a problem in firing DataGridView SelectionChanged using code, i'm working on Windows forms unsing C# on Visual Studio 2013.

I use this solution :

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
/* Code here ...  */
}
```

and fire it using a button click like this :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
 {
 ...
 dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender,e);
 ...
 }
```

Is this the right way to do this ?

Comment: Should work.  You should probably use dataGridView1 instead of sender, otherwise, the sender is a button that you're passing.  Pressing the button won't actually "select" anything, it will just run that code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Mostly when people want to do that is because they have some code they want to execute. If that's the case, refactor your code so it lives in another method.

Comment: Thank you very much @LarsTech and CodingYoshi , the first solution works but there was some problems, so i had to create new method for the part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

very simple , the following will fire `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event handler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows['row_index'].Selected = true;
}
```